# Find the total sum of a list of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list that consists of a lot of dictionaries that look like this (I inserted just the first two):

```
[
    {
        "_id": "60ca15162a42482a5fc83bcc",
        "name": "Fanta",
        "category": "Soft Drinks",
        "description": "Fresh Drink",
        "price": 14,
        "quantity": 104
    },
    {
        "_id": "60ca15162a42482a5fc83bcc",
        "name": "Fanta",
        "category": "Soft Drinks",
        "description": "Fresh Drink",
        "price": 16,
        "quantity": 104
    } ]
```

I want to get the total price. The total price looks would be like this.

```
total=(14*104)+(16*104)
```

How do I do that when I have a lot of those dictionaries inside of a list? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```py
lst = [
    {
        "_id": "60ca15162a42482a5fc83bcc",
        "name": "Fanta",
        "category": "Soft Drinks",
        "description": "Fresh Drink",
        "price": 14,
        "quantity": 104,
    },
    {
        "_id": "60ca15162a42482a5fc83bcc",
        "name": "Fanta",
        "category": "Soft Drinks",
        "description": "Fresh Drink",
        "price": 16,
        "quantity": 104,
    },
]

total = sum(d["price"] * d["quantity"] for d in lst)
print(total)
```

Prints:

```
3120
```

---

EDIT: To create a list with totals:

```py
total = [d["price"] * d["quantity"] for d in lst]
print(total)
```

Prints:

```py
[1456, 1664]
```

Comment: One more question: Is there any way I can append the total in the lst?

Comment: Instead of print can it be done with "return"?

Comment: @Wannahelp Yes, create a function a do `return total` instead of `print()`

Answer (score 0):

`sum(map(lambda x: x['price']*x['quantity'], lst))` should do the job

Comment: Map and lambda is quite ugly. If anything, use `itertools.starmap` and `operator.mul`: `sum(starmap(mul, map(itemgetter("price", "quantity"), lst)))`

Comment: Instead of `lambda`  we should make a separate function block to keep it clean!